# How import in a client script an utility method

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose to have two principle folders: lib folder and in this folder there is a utils.js file static folder with a element.js file

In the utils.js file the code is:

```
'use strict';

var Utils = {};

Utils.getPrint = function() {
    return "hello";
};

module.exports = Utils;
```

Now in the static folder the element.js file is a client script so:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
// I must import utils.js file but I don't know how do this. Something like 
var utils=require();
    $(document).ready(function() {


        });


}());
```

Anyone can help me how code I must write to import utils.js file in element.js file?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import your module from client/server side both, you need a bundler like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).

Node.js follows CommonJS module spec, which like "var module = require('module');" something, and browser doesn't follow CommonJS. It has own module spec from ES6, but still no browser supporting yet, also Node.js either.

Later, when all browser supports ES6 module system and Node.js also do(Node.js based on V8, so it will be support future ES features), then you can write the ES6 modules for browser/server both can use it, but not now.